# Spring Security forbidden error when sending valid token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have created a rest api which returns a JWT token when hit authenticate. I used the token to access protected rest end points but still get a 403 Forbidden response

```
securityconfigure class
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().cors().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
    
}

filter class

@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired 
    private jwtUtil JwtUtil;
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwt = null;
        if(authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
        {
            jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            username = JwtUtil.extractUserName(jwt);
        }
        if(username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if(JwtUtil.validateToken(jwt,userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
                
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }

}

controller

@RestController
public class HelloResource {
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Autowired 
    private jwtUtil jwtUtilToken;
    
    @RequestMapping({"/hello"})
    public String hello(){
        return "hello world";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> craeteAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) 
            throws Exception{
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate
            (new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUserName(),authenticationRequest.getPassword()));
        }
        catch(BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect username or password");
        }
        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUserName());
        final String jwt = jwtUtilToken.generateToken(userDetails);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));
    }
}
```

when i hit http://localhost:8080/hello through postman
i got below error.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-07-15T04:21:52.246+00:00",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/hello"
}
```

[image]